# Algorithmic or Mathematical way of separating decimal from floating?

Tags: algorithm, math, floating-point, decimal, exponent

Is there any mathematical or algorithmic way of dividing a floating point number into two parts (before and after) the point.

Example:

```
number=456.789
before=456
after=0.789
```

I don't want any code because I can do this in any programming language.  I want a generic algorithm preferably using arithmetic or other such operators.

Comment: Do you want us to take into account the IEEE754 float representation in memory? Can we use the math functions ceiling and floor?

Answer (score 4):

It all depends what operations are available on floating-point values:

- if you have `floor` and `ceil` then you can use one of those to get the integer part, and subtraction to get the fractional part.
- if you have division-with-remainder you can do that (using 1 as the divisor).
- if you can examine the bitwise representation of the value, knowing which bits are the exponent and mantissa, then you could use that.
- if you can view the value as a decimal string, you could split on the decimal separator (normally `.` or `,`), although scientific notation would require extra work to deal with.
- if all you have is comparison, addition and subtraction then you could do a binary search for the integer part -- establish the starting bounds by a series of exponentially increasing guesses. This is probably the most "generic" in the sense that it assumes only the fundamental mathematical operations of an ordered additive group (since you can avoid multiplication or division if you care to). But it's inconceivable that there would be a serious programming language with floating-point that doesn't provide a more efficient way.

Comment: `floor` and `ceil` fail unless they are conditional upon the sign. E.g., with the common `double`, applying `before = floor(x); after = x - before;` to -0x1p-54 will yield -1 and 1, when the result should be either 0 and -0x1p-54 or -1 and an unrepresentable value slightly smaller than 1, depending on need. It is more appropriate to use `trunc` or `fmod`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: agreed, and of course that's the right advice to give to someone who wants code in any specific language that has those things. I just don't know whether `trunc` or `modf` count as "I don't want any code" since they're defined specifically to return (one of) the values required.

Comment: @SteveJessop: +1, but your binary search can be improved. floor(x) must be in the range (x-1, x], so no exponential guessing is needed (and what would you search for?). But how exactly do you know when you've arrived at the floor? And how do you find a midpoint without either multiplication or division? (Yes, I know OP wants trunc(), not floor(), but that's easily solved by working with the absolute value.)

Comment: @rici: the search I had in mind would only use integer values (although in for example C, you'd need to put them in a `double` type if you want to go beyond `LLONG_MAX`). You know you've found the floor when you find an integer value `f` such that `f <= number` but `number < f + 1`.

Comment: @rici: oh, and you can find the midpoint without division by knowing the successive powers of two (build a table as your guesses get bigger). Then at each step of the binary search, the length of the range still to search is always a power of two, so you can find the midpoint by adding the next smaller power of two to the low bound. Or just divide, of course: I'm not saying this is all a good idea, merely that it can be done as an intellectual exercise.

Comment: @SteveJessop: cool. Why don't you edit your answer, then? I don't think the algorithm you describe in your comment is the same as "establish the starting bounds by a series of exponentially increasing guesses", or at least the quoted line is nowhere near as clear as your description above.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do the following to get what you ask for :

```
double number=456.789;
int before= number; //This type cast is equivalent to floor(number) 
double after=number-before;
```

so getting the floor of the given floating point number is the main task we are performing, where floor method just returns the largest integer not greater than the input number. This most probably done by exploiting the [floating point representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) in the memory with some language-level operations (you can not perform normal bitwise operation in floating point numbers as it is not defined). 
So AFAIU, if you do not want to use floor/type-cast you are basically doomed.